# Randomly Generated 2D Noise

Tags: c, random, procedural-generation

I'm trying to generate a random 2D grid that is procedurally generated from the [x, y] coordinates (as opposed to pre-generating a 2D array of numbers). The reason for this is that the map is potentially huge, and there is a good possibility that much of the grid will not actually be needed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
double value_at(Grid *grid, int seed, int x, int y) {
  srand(seed + x + y * grid->width);
  return (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
}
```

UPDATE: A requirement is that `value_at` has referential transparency (to the extent possible). So the following must hold true:

```
int i = value_at(grid, seed, 100, 100);
int j = value_at(grid, seed, 100, 100);

assert(i == j);
```

In other words, if I call `value_at` with the same arguments it should *always* give the same result no matter how many times I call it during the execution of the program.
The reason for this is because I am trying to generate random terrain, which will involve interpolation between different grid points; it is also possible that the user will re-visit a certain point within the grid.

It's generating grids properly, however I'm seeing a lot of regularities in the output:

[image: Grid 1]
[image: Grid 2]

You can see that there is a sort of "grain" that sends lines moving diagonally through the output.

I'm doing some research on it but I'm having some trouble finding ways to do this. Does anybody have an idea on how to get the grids to be a bit more "random"?

UPDATE: Thanks to the links provided by ldgabbay, I've added a simple rotating hash function that looks like this:

```
int simple_hash(int * is, int count) {
  // this contains a bunch of arbitrarily chosen prime numbers
  int i;
  unsigned int hash = 80238287;

  for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    hash = (hash << 4) ^ (hash >> 28) ^ (is[i] * 5449 % 130651);
  }

  return hash % 75327403;
}
```

Then the `value_at` function looks like this:

```
double value_at(Grid *grid, int seed, int x, int y) {
  int is[] = {x, y, seed};
  srand(simple_hash(is, 3));
  return (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
}
```

Here are some sample grids that it generates:

[image: Grid 3]
[image]

Comment: Stop seeding the get-function. A rand-seed, something like  `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));` belongs at the top of `main()`; **once** for the process unless you're purposely trying to regenerate a same-sequence (and it doesn't appear here that is the case). Start with that. (unrelated: the images do a marvelous job of testing my pixel refresh burn-down if I slowly scroll the page =P).

Comment: I've added an additional requirement to the question. If I only seed once at the beginning of the process, then the requirement does not hold.

Comment: So you want something that is random, but only *once*, then repetitious? It would seem to me knowing an init-state and having the image in storage for retrieval (even as a matrix of `double`) would be the mechanism of achieving that. Or I'm still not understanding the *real* problem (which isn't unlikely lately).

Comment: If 2 calls to `value_at()` given the same parameters must generate the same result, best not to use the system `srand()/rand()` as then those functions become useless for the rest of code.  Better to employ your own `robbrit_rand()`.  Much internet source code available for good random() functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a subtle flaw in your use of `srand` to make the `value_at` deterministic. Normally, a random number generator is seeded once and the numbers that come out of it are pseudo random. However, in this method, you are looking at the very first random number to come out of the random number generator for different seeds. This may not be as random as you'd like. I would expect this is highly dependent on the implementation of the random number generator on your system.

Since you have the requirement that you can't save your random sequence, I have a few ideas.

1)

Try altering the formula you use to alter the random seed.  Right now, your seed is changing very predictably as you move across the grid. (e.g. seed, seed+1, seed+2, ..., seed+width, seed+width+1, etc.) What you want is:

```
srand(seed + hash(x + y * grid->width));
```

where `hash` is something simple that maps a number in [0, width*height) to another number in that range, but less predictable.

Some simple hash functions can be found [here](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html).

2)

Pop a deterministic number of random numbers off the random number generator before getting your random value. So, before your return statement, add a line like:

```
for (i=0; i!=skip; ++i) rand();
```

You can set `skip` to a fixed number, or you could even make it a deterministic function of x, y, or even seed.

Comment: Rather than `srand(seed + hash(x + y * grid->width));`, would not `hash(seed + x + y * grid->width));` make more sense?

Comment: Yeah, that could be done too. The point is to stop the argument to `srand` from being predictable.

Comment: Perfect, works great! I ended up doing an adaptation of the rotating hash function from your list with a few extra big prime numbers thrown in until I got something that was suitably random-looking. I'll post the code in the question.